# save config payment method button doesno work 1.9.2.2

Tags: ce-1.9.2.2

i tried installing paytabs to magento 1.9.2.2 the save config button on the payment method page doesnot work. it doesnot pop up error and nothing happens. 
i tried diabling paytabs extension. still it is the same

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure that this extension use old style adminhtml router. Could you copy and paste here `<routers>` node from `etc/config.xml` file?